# How to query an item from an sql object (CRATE DB)

Tags: sql, crate

I am trying to use the new crate db. [link](https://crate.io/)
I have a table which contains an "infrastructure" and "network" objects:

```
CREATE TABLE servers (infrastructure object(strict) as (
                #etc...
                os_name string, 
                #etc...
                network array(object as 
                (etc.., hosting_id string, etc... ))
```

I need to query th os_name from "infrastructure" and hosting_id from network array. How I do it? I tried to google to find the right syntax but had no succes. I want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE infrastructure[os_name] = "some value"
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE infrastructure["network"]["hosting_id"] = "some value"
```

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column. Better change your table design

Comment: Is this `MySQL` ... have never seen such syntax. may be am missing some

Comment: sorry. This is not Mysql, but it uses sql language. https://crate.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ANY()](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/queries.html#any-array) is your friend, but be aware that it does not with arrays of objects. So you need to also consider [this information](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/queries.html#object-arrays). The solution below works for the latest Crate version 1.0.1:

```
SELECT * FROM servers 
WHERE 
  os_name = 'some value' 
AND 
  'some value' = ANY(network['hosting_id']);
```